# Underscore formatting bug, excited (maybe) by subscripts of nothing.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrices not rendered correctly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/544/matrices-not-rendered-correctly)

I'm trying to display old-style notations for combinations, that is, ${}_nC_r$ for the thing now typically written $n\choose r$.  To get the "$n$" here you must put a subscript on an empty expression, thus:  $\$${}_nC_r$\$$.

I can't get this to work correctly when the trailing subscript is multi-character. If I want $n\choose 11$ and put the braces where I'd expect them, it comes out like this: ${}_nC_{11}$.  Note that I didn't quote anything; the system simply refuses to interpret the TeX.

There's no problem if the *first* subscript is multi-character ${}_{11}C_9$ works OK.

It looks like the problem is that one or t'other underscore obscures the trailing dollar sign, so math mode isn't exited properly.  If I try the $n\choose 11$ example again and include another math expression before the next paragraph break, it comes out like this: ${}_nC_{11}$ is zero by definition when $n<11$.

Comment: Use backslash, e.g. `{}\\_nC\\_{11}` -> ${}\_nC\_{11}$ to avoid Markdown interpreting the _underscores_ as italic.

Comment: @KennyTM, why can't we escape text inside of the dollar signs like on MO (by allowing mathJax to render inside of code tags)?

Comment: @978: that's what http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/551/allow-texification-in-code-tags is about, meh.

Comment: @KennyTM: I find your support for the status-quo incredibly frustrating.  It's not hard to do, so just help us campaign for it.

Comment: @978: What else you want to do? I've already filed a feature-request to mimic the MO behavior. I do not control the back-end, if the admins at SO Inc. decided it's not an issue there's nothing we can do.

Comment: @KennyTM: Did they decide that?  If so, we should just keep bugging them about it until they do something (that is what we can do!).