# MathJax preview broken when equations contain `\label`s

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, markdown-preview

One can use `\tag`, `\label`, `\ref` and `\eqref` the usual way in MathJax (including references turned into links), e.g.

> ```
> $ a = b \tag{a}\label{a} $
> ```
>
> and later
>
> ```
> $ \eqref{a} $
> ```

$ a = b \tag{a}\label{a} $

and later

$ \eqref{a} $

but unfortunately the block containing the `\label` breaks once one further edits - this is probably due to the label being apparently "reused" for a "new" tag, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I guess a simple fix would be not parsing `\label` while editing a question, although an even better solution would of course be somehow letting MathJax know the previous instance of the label shall be discarded.

Comment: A suboptimal fix might be putting the whole post into [`$\begingroup$ ... $\endgroup$`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup)

Comment: The preview code could use MathJax's ability to reset the labels in order to resolve this issue (the preview code was written before `\label` and `\ref` were available in MathJax).

Comment: As a temporary work-around, you could add `$\def\label#1{}$` at the top of your question/answer while you are editing it, and remove it just before submitting the answer.

Comment: @DavideCervone Nice workaround, thanks! I hope it'll be fixed though...

Comment: See my [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/mathjax-editing-preview-improvements-userscript) that includes a user-script to work around this issue until the editing code is updated.

Comment: The editing code has been updated, so the preview code should now process `\label` macros properly.  You should no longer need to use the temporary work-arounds that were necessary before.

Comment: @DavideCervone Looks great, there also seems to be no more delay for reprogressing changed TeX