# Turn off MathJax noErrors extension during preview

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

The MathJax noErrors extension causes $\rm\LaTeX$ expressions that contain errors to show the original $\rm\LaTeX$ code rather than an error message.  That is certainly appropriate for viewing questions, so that if there is an error, you can at least see the $\rm\LaTeX$.  But when you are writing a post, it would often be helpful to see the error message instead, so you can correct the $\rm\LaTeX$ more easily.  So I propose that the noErrors extension be disabled during the MathJax typesetting of question and answer previews.

This can be accomplished by changing the `RestartMJ` function in `mathjax-editing.js` to be

```
function SetNoErrors (state) {
  HUB.Config({TeX:{noErrors:{disabled:state}}});
}
function RestartMJ () {
  pending = HUB.cancelTypeset = !1;
  HUB.Queue(
    [SetNoErrors,!0],
    ["Typeset",HUB,preview],
    [SetNoErrors,!1]
  );
}
```

You could also clear up the [problem with labels in preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/mathjax-preview-broken-when-equations-contain-labels) by adding

```
    ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
```

to the beginning of the `HUB.Queue` call above.

Comment: +1 This would be very helpful when debugging hairy code.